# Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices. Suppose all the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are distinct.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Question: Let $A$ and $B$ be $n\times n$ matrices. Suppose all the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are distinct. Prove or disprove the following statements.

> $1$. If  $AB=BA$, then each eigen vector of $A$ is an eigen vector of $B$.

> $2$. If $AB-BA=2B$ and $\lambda$ is an eigen value of $A$ then $\lambda-2$ is also an eigen value of $A$.

Consider $2\times 2$ matrices as follows
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0\\
0 & 1\\
\end{pmatrix}$$ and
$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
then consequently we have $$AB=BA=\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0\\
0 & 0\\
\end{pmatrix}$$
Subtracting the eigen values down the matrix and checking its eigen vectors satisfied $1$.Tried looking for more, they satisfied it, I doubt it being correct! Similar is the situation with $2$.

Thanks.

Comment: For 1. use the fact that the eigenspaces are one-dimensional.

Comment: I can see that $\lambda +2$ would be an eigenvalue in 2. Don't know about $\lambda -2$.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts @AlvinL. Didn't get your hint for 1. I mean how can I relate that eigenvectors of $A$ and $B$ are same? How $\lambda+2$? Please mention the matrices on which you were trying to get a conclusion :/

Comment: The question asks about all $n\times n$ matrices. For 2. just note that if $Ax=\lambda x$ for some $x\neq 0$, then $$(AB-BA)x = 2Bx \Leftrightarrow A(Bx) = (\lambda +2)Bx\quad \text{(assuming }Bx\neq 0\text{)} $$
Maybe $\lambda -2$ is an eigenvalue, I don't know at the moment.

Comment: What I meant to say with "assuming $Bx\neq 0$" part is that would allow the conclusion that $\lambda+2$ is an eigenvalue of $A$.

Answer (score 1):

Part.1

$$Av_k=\lambda_k v_k\Rightarrow ABv_k=BAv_k=\lambda_kBv_k\Rightarrow Bv_k\in Ei(A,\lambda_k)$$

Since all eigenvalues of $A$ are distinct, $$\Rightarrow Dim(Ei(A,\lambda_k))=1\Rightarrow Bv_k=c \cdot v_k$$

Since $v_k\neq0\Rightarrow v_k$ is also an eigenvector of $B$.

Part.2

The problem says "all eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are distinct", there are maybe some ambiguities. Suppose $A$ has eigenvalues $a_1,...,a_n$, $B$ has eigenvalues $b_1,...,b_n$, Does the problem mean:

$|\{a_1,...,a_n,b_1,...,b_n\}|=2n$

or

$|\{a_1,...,a_n\}|=n,|\{b_1,...,b_n\}|=n,~|\{a_1,...,a_n,b_1,...,b_n\}|\le 2n$

Comment: Here "Distinct EigenValues" is ambigous : It could even mean A & B may ( or may not ) have repeated EigenValues but the Intersection of these two sets of EigenValues = { } ! In other words , A & B have no common EigenValues !